# Move IIS Logs to AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I have a requirement to upload IIS logs 7 days older to AWS S3 Bukcet. By using below code I am able to access AWS folders under bucket

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\AWSPowerShell.psd1"
$AKey = ""
$SKey = ""
$source = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\*"
$outputpath = "C:\scripts\Logs\logs3.txt"
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $AKey -SecretKey $SKey

function Get-Subdirectories {
    param  (
        [string] $BucketName,
        [string] $KeyPrefix,
        [bool] $Recurse
    )

    @(Get-S3Object -BucketName $BucketName -KeyPrefix $KeyPrefix -Delimiter '/') | Out-Null

    if ($AWSHistory.LastCommand.Responses.Last.CommonPrefixes.Count -eq 0) {
        return
    }

    $AWSHistory.LastCommand.Responses.Last.CommonPrefixes

    if ($Recurse) {
        $AWSHistory.LastCommand.Responses.Last.CommonPrefixes | ForEach-Object { Get-Subdirectories -BucketName $BucketName -KeyPrefix $_ -Recurse $Recurse }
    }
}

function Get-S3Directories {
    param  (
        [string] $BucketName,
        [bool] $Recurse = $false
    )
    Get-Subdirectories -BucketName $BucketName -KeyPrefix '/' -Recurse $Recurse 
}
```

Now if I type `Get-S3Directories -BucketName backups` I get the following output:

```
SERVER-xxx-OLogs/
SERVER-xxx-untime-logs /
SERVER-xxx-FRLogs/
SERVER-oooooRLogs/
SERVER-IISLogFiles/
```

Now the challenge is I have to move IIS older than 7 days under `SERVER-IISLogFiles/` Directory

So I have created this

```
$sfolder = Get-S3Directories -BucketName Backups
Foreach ($folder in $sfolder) {
    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

    Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey $AKey -SecretKey $SKey -StoreAs For_Move
    Initialize-AWSDefaults -ProfileName For_Move -Region US-east-1

    Start-Transcript -path $outputpath -Force
    foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem $source -include *.log -recurse) {
        if ($i.CreationTime -lt ($(Get-Date).AddDays(-7))) {
            $fileName = (Get-ChildItem $i).Name
            $parentFolderName = Split-Path (Split-Path $i -Parent) -Leaf
            Write-S3Object -BucketName $folder -File $i
        }
    }
}
Stop-Transcript
```

I am not entirely sure whether its going to move to `SERVER-IISLogFiles/` Directory, not sure if I am missing anything here apart from this, I doubt its going to keep the folder structure of local IIS folder on IIS

Comment: It's not very clear from what your actual question is. As far as I can get -- You want to upload .log files that are older than 7 day from `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` to the S3 bucket `Backups` into the S3 'folder' called `SERVER-IISLogFiles`?

Comment: yes you got it, now the problem is I want it to schedule it so every 7 days logs older than 7 days will move to aws s3 bucket and keeping iis logs folder structure, so the script finds logs older than 7 days and move to the same folder

Comment: Why don't you try to create a temporary folder which is going to contain all the files that should be transferred with the original structure. On the S3 you can then open a new folder in the IISLogFiles directory, which has the timestamp for it's name, and just upload the temp file you've created earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

You could try and use the following method to create your folder structure within the S3 Bucket. Using the Key Prefix parameter and splitting your path to your folders should work.

```
$Params = @{
    BucketName = 'backup'
    Folder = '$Source or whatever path'
    KeyPrefix = (Split-Path -Path 'C:\PATHTO\SOURCE\DIRECTORY' -Leaf).TrimEnd('\')
    Recurse = $true
    Region = 'REGION'
}
Write-S3Object @Params
```

Comment: Hmm I think it won't keep the folder structure I will 1st move the files and upload

Comment: lemme check that

Comment: I should be uploading under a key called SERVER-IISLogFiles/ under backups bucket

Comment: If you want that to be the root directory for all your subdirectories in source, then yes! I hope my answer helped you in some way!

Comment: yes what I did is I renamed  the local folder same as subdirectory name

Comment: Now what I did is 1> a powershell script will move the logs to a local folder,2> s3 script will move it to aws and than 3rd command will delete it